# xcode crashes saying, "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" and connection is not linked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, signals

Why does my app keep crashing, please? This seems to be the problem,

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of typeNSException
(lldb)
```

but I'm not 100% what it means. I have checked that all the buttons and text fields are labeled with the correct identifier.

!!  console

[console one][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e17Sd.png

[console 2][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARwP.png

Comment: You should scroll upwards in console , there will be a message there  which gives more info about the error or if you can, please share the complete error in console

Comment: first share the complete error in console that mentioned above or click the warning on `issue navigator ` then can see `all messages` on the top select that then you can find the detailed reason

Comment: @3stud1ant3 HI i have added a photo in my question above now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry to say this still is not the message that can help identify the problem , this is not complete console message,

Comment: Check your outlet connections

Comment: Add complete console log for us to check where things went wrong.

Also go through some tutorials for using breakpoint in Xcode. You need to add an exception breakpoint to point to the exact line where crash took place.

Comment: Okay I have screenshot the console, but couldn't do the last part, but it's just the code in the question. It always goes to, " class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" in the Debug navigator. Thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception in exceptions screen in Xcode and the next time your application crashes it will show the line on code, SIGABRT is a very general error and occurs for various reasons

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your outlet connections. If you ever renamed or removed any of your outlets via code, the old outlet may still be connected in the Interface Builder. Check the connections in both code and the Interface Builder